# How to create an Overflow menu and combine it with an option menu?

Tags: android, menu, overflow, android-studio

I am new in Android development. I want to ask how can I create an overflow menu with two items. Also, how can I combine it with an option menu I already did, which looks like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    MenuInflater blabla = getMenuInflater();
    blabla.inflate(R.menu.options_menu ,menu);
    return true;


}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.OurSponsors:
            Intent i = new Intent("com.--.------.------");
            startActivity(i);
            break;

        case R.id.exit:
            finish();
            break;

    }
    return false;
}
```

xml

```
 <item
android:title="Our Sponsors"
android:id="@+id/OurSponsors"
android:icon="@drawable/image"
/>


<item
        android:title="Exit"
        android:id="@+id/exit"
        android:icon="@drawable/exit"
           />
```

I am a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the developer page related to that http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource.html.

You will want to add `android:showAsAction="collapseActionView"` (or `android:showAsAction="never"` depending on your API level) to each menu item in the XML layout

Comment: i am a beginner so if you can give me a full tutorial showing how to create an overflow menu this will be awesome !

Comment: You just add the above code to your menu items, so if you create another menu item just add that attribute in the XML or if you want those two items in the overflow, then just add that attribute in each item in the XML. Android will automatically create the overflow menu if you use the above attributes.